How to access window object in background.js file [Chrome Extension]
I am trying to write a custom Chrome extension that will implement a caching-type behavior.
Currently, in Microsoft, all custom controls are fetched from the server and rendered within an iframe. Consequently, whenever a developer makes changes to a control, they must upload the updated HTML, publish it, and then refresh the page to view the modifications.
To expedite development, we're considering creating a custom Chrome extension. This extension would intercept the requests made to Microsoft's server and instead return the content from a local server (typically hosted on localhost), where developers can make changes to the web resources.
I've drafted the following code, which mostly functions as intended. However, a challenge arises because we need to access the window object within background.js, which is restricted in Chrome extensions due to security policies.
here is my code snippet.
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (details) => {
    // Check if the request URL matches the one you want to intercept
    if (details.url.includes("webresources/gc_relatedproductcontrol")) {
      var myblob = new Blob(["<html><body>Hello</body></html>"], {
        type: 'text/html'
      });
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);         
      return { redirectUrl: url };
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest", "main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);

Another thing I have tried is that creating some redirection. here is that code
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (details) => {
    // Check if the request URL matches the one you want to intercept
    if (details.url.includes("webresources/gc_relatedproductcontrol")) {      
      return { redirectUrl: "http://locahost:3000/gc_relatedproductcontrol.html" };
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest", "main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);


There's no way. It's unclear from the code why you need window and what's wrong with redirection.

Actually I want to access the method URL.createObjectURL  which is only available in window object I am not able to create blob without using this and redirection does not work.

URL.createObjectURL is not implemented for service workers, so you won't be able to use it in ManifestV3 in Chrome. You can use declarativeNetRequest instead of webRequest and redirect the URL to a page in your extension or to a data: URL.

There are two common ways to debugger a web resource file without publishing.
One is using Fiddler, read more here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/streamline-javascript-development-fiddler-autoresponder.
Another is using the Chrome Override feature, kind like Fiddler but it is a buildin feature in Chrome. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides.

thanks for the information it really helped me... but looked in to but I am facing some issues. take the following example.
i have lot of resources and return local version of all of them..
for example dist folder contains all the register webresources so when I enable fiddler  it should return all webresources from that folder. can you suggest me the regex pattern in fiddler that I can used I don't add rule for each webresources.

also note that webresources can js or HTML files
